# LWC Not Redering HTML

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, vs-code

I am starting out creating a lighting web component, following the Hello World Example.
I have set up a Sandbox environment and Authorised the org in VS Code.
I have set up a project with manifest and retrieved manifest from org using SFDX
I then create an LWC and set up the 3 files and respectively..

.html

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="HelloWorld" icon-name="custom:custom14">
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
      <p>Hello, {greeting}!</p>
      <lightning-input
        label="Name"
        value={greeting}
        onchange={changeHandler}
      ></lightning-input>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

.js

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {
  greeting = "World";
  changeHandler(event) {
    this.greeting = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="helloWorld">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Which are just cut and paste from examples. These reder well in playground (although the xml file is not required.

My problem is when I deploy the code to Salesforce and then render the component, it has no html below the component element

[From Chrome Dev Tools]

```
<div data-component-id="helloWorld" data-aura-rendered-by="637:0" class="flexipageComponent" data-aura-class="flexipageComponent">
<c-hello-world data-data-rendering-service-uid="227" data-aura-rendered-by="639:0"></c-hello-world>
</div>
```

I am a bit stuck how to debug this, it seems the code is not being rendered properly. I'd appreciate some guidance about how to attack this problem.

Comment: That's odd. I copy-pasted this to my VS Code, dropped in a Lightning App, and it renders correctly (and works as expected). Try making a scratch org or try another org and see if this problem persists. If you'd like, I can make you a gist with my exact files.

Comment: How did you try to render the component? The component works as expected and visible in the DOM when I tried.

Comment: I added it in the Visual Force Page builder to the standard Sales Page. The component renders an empty html element both in the Web Designer and the actual page.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the code you have posted in the  question,tried it works for me

html:

```
   <template>
<lightning-card title="HelloWorld" icon-name="custom:custom14">
  <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
    <p>Hello, {greeting}!</p>
    <lightning-input
      label="Name"
      value={greeting}
      onchange={changeHandler}
    ></lightning-input>
  </div>
</lightning-card>
```

Js:

```
 import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
 export default class Greeting extends LightningElement {
    greeting = "World";
    changeHandler(event) {
      this.greeting = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

If i check your error you posted

```
  <div data-component-id="helloWorld" data-aura-rendered-by="637:0" class="flexipageComponent" data-aura-class="flexipageComponent">
  <c-hello-world data-data-rendering-service-uid="227" data-aura-rendered-by="639:0"></c-hello-world>
```

why these component with Kebab  case  notation error "c-hello-world"  ?  seems like you posted wrong error

Comment: FYI - https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lwc_track.htm

Comment: That's an acute observation, but not the problem here. It renders in my org just fine.

Comment: @SfdcBat Oh, that's a sweet find! I wondered why it worked :p

Comment: thanks @sfdcbat.

Comment: @sfdcfox event i have tried the same code no issue for me.i just updated the answer

Comment: Hi @Annappa PH, I added the track decoration, however the problem persists. I agree the code/syntax all looks fine. As such I think the problem sits in either the way it is being deployed or something in the config of the instance. Any clues about where to investigate the problem from this angle would be appreciated.

Comment: Further, my lwc project in VS Code is called helloWorld and it gets converted to kebab text as c-hello-world with the c- prefix which is global?

Comment: i didnt get above comment. you can create one more scratch org and try it . that may work

Answer (score 0):

Complete noob issue. I didn't save all in VS Code and it was sending a blank html file in.

Oh well, the only way is up.

It'd be good to understand if there is a way to view the files on the server.